# Java Swing : What is wrong with this method

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

```
private void addButtonPressed() {
    String newbarcode = barcodeTF.getText();
    String newitemName = itemNameTF.getText();
    String newprice = priceTF.getText();

    if (newbarcode.equals("") || newitemName.equals("") || newprice.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Enter Full Details");
    } else {
        stock.addCheckoutItem(newbarcode, newitemName, newprice);
        CheckoutItem newBasket = stock.findItemByName(newbarcode);
        stockList.setSelectedValue(newBasket, true);
        clearAllTextFields();
    }
}
```

It is called through an actionlistener on one of the buttons within my program however keeps throwing out exception errors when running.. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit : Exception details added below.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EditStockGUI.addButtonPressed(EditStockGUI.java:447)
    at EditStockGUI.access$4(EditStockGUI.java:446)
    at EditStockGUI$10.actionPerformed(EditStockGUI.java:352)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What exception?  On which line?

Comment: Okay, which line is `EditStockGUI.java:447`?

Comment: Hi!. Thank you for the quick responses.  `String newbarcode = barcodeTF.getText();`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Then `barcodeTF` is probably `null`, which probably means you are shadowing your variables